# Referencing repository files at a given commit in gitlab wiki

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab Markdown has support for references to files in the repository structure, like:

`[README](doc/README)`

or

`[README](doc/README#L13)`

But are there ways to reference files and lines in these files, but from a given commit, at least in the Wiki ?

Maybe something like:

`[README](1ab3fa71:doc/README#L13)`

or using the file hash id like:

`[README](9a27b101#L13)`

Comment: At least it works for comments/issues like this `[here](../tree/671cb267/Python Scripts/anyscript.py#L14)`

Answer (score 11):

To use *relative links* from wiki to the repository (or wise versa) is *not* supported officially  according to [Gitlab's documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#links) (cited from v11.5, still valid for v15.3):

> Note: Relative links do not allow referencing project files in a wiki page or wiki page in a project file. The reason for this is that, in GitLab, wiki is always a separate Git repository. For example, I'm a reference-style link will point the link to wikis/style when the link is inside of a wiki markdown file.

There is, however, a syntax which seems to work currently:

```
[[README|/../blob/1ab3fa71/doc/README#L13]]
```

**But be aware: all text of the same paragraph will just be lost!**

I work around that by phrasing like this, which renders like expected for *Gitlab CE v11.3.0* at least:

```
Here you see xyz:
* [[README|/../blob/1ab3fa71/doc/README#L13]]
```

The root-anchored link (`/../blob/<version>/<path-to-file>`) ensures that it works from every Wiki page independently from their nesting depth.
For sure this syntax also works for branch names or any other relative link like `/../tree/1ab3fa71/doc` for example.

Comment: In my experience (GitLab 14.8.2) using this type of link does not drop text of entire paragraph, just some rendering block. Workaround is to enclose link in empty linking markdown: []()[[README|/../blob/1ab3fa71/doc/README#L13]][]()
Or in span element, when you are using HTML syntax: <span>[[README|/../blob/1ab3fa71/doc/README#L13]]</span>

Answer (score 5):

One way I've found that, for the most part, works is to mouseover the line of code that you want to reference in the relevant file. While doing that, click the link icon that appears in the lefthand-side gutter to copy the line reference. With it copied, you then use a slightly revised version of the path in the copied URI.

Here is an example of a link copied using the gutter icon:

```
https://gitlab.com/settermjd/mezzio-sms-sender-api/-/blob/main/src/App/src/Handler/SMSReplyHandler.php#L23
```

This is the revised path that I used in a commit. Note the parent directory reference prior to `main/`:

```
/../main/src/App/src/Handler/SMSReplyHandler.php#L23
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe long after the battle, but I found a workaround : Simply make a link to a page where the README.md is. And that's it !

To get the link simply go to a page which displays the document, copy the URL, make a link to that address, append #L with the line number.

Exemple :

> [Readme Pelargos](http://192.168.80.250:10080/project-root/android/Pelargos/blob/develop/README.md#L47)

Comment: Having `host:port/serverroot` explicitly in the URL makes it difficult to host that repo somewhere else, should the need arise.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that the file reference in the gitlab wiki, references files from the wiki repository itself and not from the project repository (source code repository).

However, when you make a reference to a hash, it knows if the hash refers to a commit or a file, so you can make references to a specific file from the project repository.

Comment: I meant "relative" references. But absolute links was what we used as a workaround.